# Cronjob Laravel Error There are no commands defined in the "process" namespace

Tags: laravel, database, cron

I run the code for cronjob summary-operational

> sudo php artisan process:summary-operational "2023-01-11" "2023-01-12"

But i have error message There are no commands defined in the "process" namespace. What should i do?

Thanks Before

Run the code for cronjob summary-operational

Comment: check the `'app/Console/Kernel.php'` and see if the command is registered properly

Comment: https://pastebin.com/Auv9Xsbh file kernel.php, the file must be execution or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that your console command's signature has the following format:

```php
protected $signature = 'process:summary-operational {arg1} {arg2}';
```

In addition, `arg1` and `arg2` will take your dates.

Ex:

```php
$fromDate = $this->argument('arg1');
$toDate = $this->argument('arg2');
```